# gsutil path name not passed from the command line to the destination bucket

Tags: sdk, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I have spotted an odd change to the Google SDK I cannot see any release notes about.

It appears somewhere between versions 4.28 and 4.34 the way path names are passed through the gsutil command have altered.

Before:

```
gsutil cp myfolder/myfile.csv gs://mybucket/
```

Would copy the file into a sub folder called `gs://mybucket/myfolder`

Now, with the latest version, it is only copied to the top folder specified `gs://mybucket/`

The issue I have is that I have dozens of batch files which all do the following...

```
for %%f in (./Myfolder/*.csv) do (
   call gsutil cp Myfolder/%%f gs://mis_sc/
)
```

Now I realise its a simple (but rather tedious) change to add the folder on the end of all of my gsutil commands but we have a mix of versions across PC's and if the older version runs with changed script I get two folders the same name, one under the other. Also the logic was the folder name on the network = bucket name so the jobs can be very generic.

We have tested on two PC's, pre and post upgrade to ensure its not a PC config causing the difference in behaviour.

Any ideas, was this a deliberate change?

We are concerned that if we do update everything, will it ever revert back?

Thanks

Steve

Answer (score 0):

The "Before" behavior you describe is not how gsutil was ever supposed to have worked: As noted [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp#how-names-are-constructed), "copying individually named files will result in objects named by the final path component of the source files".

If you are able to get gsutil to reproduce the "Before" behavior you describe using an older version of gsutil please provide the details to reproduce it: the gsutil version, bucket contents before copying, and source folder/object name. You can get to all the previous versions under gs://pub/gsutil_*